# Access method and varaible in MainActivity from extern BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

My MainActivity class is big. Therefor, I want to seperate the inner class BroadcastListener into normal class but I am facing the problem that I do not know how can I  access the method and varaible in the MainActivity from this BroadcastReceiver class. Is there a way to do that?

I appreciate any help.

```js
 private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

                    // This method"deliverBestAccessPoint" is in MainActivity class
      String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
      //I want to set the "textwifi" varaible in MainActivity
      textWifi.setText(a.toString());
     }

   }

   else if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one interface as

```
 interface ReceiverInteface
{
 onBroadcastReceive();

}
```

let mainActivity implements this interface

```
    mainactivity implements ReceiverInterface

{
   @override
     onBroadcastReceive()
{ 
   //do all you task here
}

}
```

And `BroadCastReceiverListner Class`

pass refrence of interface from Mainactiivty.

```
   ReceiverInteface recevierListner;
    BroadcastReceiverListener(ReceiverInteface mListner)
    {
     recevierListner = mListner;
    }

private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
recevierListner.onBroadcastReceive();
}
             }

}
```

Comment: can you please take a look at you last code section. shall I add it in my MainActivity class? Because with you way then I still have the inner BroacdcastReceiver class in MainActivity?

Comment: no make BroadcastReceiverListener  as a seperate class...just pass reference of interface from mainactivity

Comment: sorry to bother you again but how can I pass reference of interface from mainactivity?