# How can I pass reference of interface from mainactivity?

Tags: android

How can I  pass reference of interface from mainactivity? Can some one give me an example? See the below comment for context:

[Access method and varaible in MainActivity from extern BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576055/access-method-and-varaible-in-mainactivity-from-extern-broadcastreceiver/29576335?noredirect=1#comment47303907_29576335)

Comment: You can use `Intent`s to pass data between activities. Have you tried using an `Intent`?

Comment: I wanted to try what the answer meant. I thought I can use Intent to pass data to the activity but in my case I want to pass from the activity

Comment: You can pass data **from** an activity **to** another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put into `Intent` all objects you want. For example

```
intent.putExtra("interface_object", myIntarfaceObject);
```

and then

```
myIntarfaceObject = (MyInterface) intent.getExtras().get("interface_object")
```

Comment: I want to  pass reference of interface from MainActivity to broadcastReceiver class and from Activity to Activity. does that work for activity to class?

Comment: It doesn't matter what component would receive this Intent. It will work.