# Android two-way service communication

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I have an activity and a local bound service. I've got the bound service up and running fine, so I can handle communication from the client to the server, through functions on the server/binder interface.

However I need two way communication, the service at some point will need to notify the activity (and the user) that something as happened, and needs to wait for a user action before proceeding. In other words, I need the servers calls to the clients to be synchronous or blocking. I.e. when the service calls a function it will pass a few parameters over to the client, which will trigger an AlertDialog for the user to use, and their options will determine the return status code sent back to the service. Until this point, I want the Service to halt and wait until it has recieved the response, which will then determine what it does from there (service continues to run, service shuts down etc.)

So is there a way in Android to do this? I need to get a reference to my activity, and it also needs to expose these blocking methods so I can call them from the service and then wait for a response. I've got an interface for my client activity, but I'm struggling on how to get this over to the service. I don't want to use Serialization and add the reference as an Intent extra, as both the client and service have many members which I do not want to be Serializable.

Thanks.

Comment: you have "bound local service" right? then pass the callback interface  to the service and it can later on call some method of that interface

Comment: Please be more specific! How do I pass the interface to the service? As a serializable intent extra? If so then we already had this discussion on the last question, and it isn't a solution

Comment: no, no extra, just pass a reference of your interface

Comment: You're still not being specific, by specific, I mean please post some code. Where do I pass this reference, I can't access the constructor.

Comment: ok read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder do you see `/** method for clients */` and one method that your activity can call:  `public int getRandomNumber()`  ? then add another method called for example `public void registerCallback(MyCallback callback)` and call it from your activity

Comment: I literally just realised I could do this a few moments ago, makes sense now. Let's see if I can get it to work. Thanks very much for the help, if you want to post this as an answer I can mark it up?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [BroadCasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to send info from service to Activity.
2. Every call of `startService()` inside Activity class will just call [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) method of service class, so you can send message to it inside Intent.
3. Use [Service binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) to make your own info transfer.

Comment: 2 isn't really feasible in this case because I'd need to Serialize the reference to my activity and every object member it contains. I'm already using 3 for the communication to the service, I'm not sure if it makes sense to make the activity also act as a service, so I've got two services communicating, is that even possible?
1 is probably the most feasible option I'm seeing at the moment, just actually came across this solution: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/01/05/learning-android-getting-a-service-to-communicate-with-an-activity/

Comment: You can put your activity inside `Intent` like it was [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579394/how-can-i-pass-reference-of-interface-from-mainactivity/29579772#29579772) with interface implementation. In this way you can put activity reference into `startService()`.

Comment: That seems promising, it seems to require the object to be serializable though, which I don't want to do, as it contains objects I can't make Serializable (WifiManager)

Comment: Serializing needs to save in String, but in Intent no need to do that. Just try.

Comment: I did try, even without using "putSerializable", I used putExtras and it still threw an error for lack of Serializable

Comment: @dahui why dont you just use "local bound service" ??? what do you need that extras for?

Comment: pskink, I'm using the local bound service, got it working, post yours as an answer if you want an upvote/marked answer