# How can I add more item to ListView through service?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity {
        private MyListViewHelper mTimelineHelper;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mListViewHelper = new MyListViewHelper(); 
        mListViewHelper.createListView();

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
}
```

MyService class:

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

        private int mCount = 0;

        public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;

        private static MyListViewHelper mListViewHelper;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // cancel if already existed
            if (mTimer != null) {
                mTimer.cancel();
            } else {
                // recreate new
                mTimer = new Timer();
            }

            // schedule task
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);



        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }

        private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask implements LocationListener {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE
                    ...........
                    mCount++;
                    if(mCount==4){
                       mListViewHelper = new MyListViewHelper()
                       mListViewHelper.addItemToList("ABCD");
                    } 
                }

                });
        public boolean isMainActivityRunning(string packageName) {
             ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
             List<RunningTaskInfo> tasksInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 

             for (int i = 0; i < tasksInfo.size(); i++) {
                    if(tasksInfo.get(i).baseActivity.getPackageName.toString().equals(packageName)
                  return true;
                  }

          return false;
          }     
        }
    }
```

MyListViewHelper class:

```
public class MyListViewHelper {
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<String> mArrayList;

    public MyListViewHelper () {
    }

    public void createListView(){
        mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // I make a short version,so we suppose adapter is already prepared here
        mListView.setadapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addItemToList(String myString){
        mArrayList.add(myString);
        adapter.notifiDateSetChanged();
}
 }
```

What I want is for every 10 seconds, service will do something, and then if it do that 4 times, I will add one item to ListView. I forgot to save logcat before change it back to the time before I edited, so there is no logcat, sorry for that. But I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with others and the problem is just somewhere in the code above since I'm leanring Android and I don't have much knowledge about Service. Please teach me to fix that!

Comment: Well if it were up to me, I would create a normal listview in the activity and from the service whenever the count reaches I would send a broadcast. In the activity I would have a broadcast receiver, and there (onRecieve), I would add items to the list and notify the adapter of change

Answer (score 1):

You could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to tell your `Activity` that the `Service` is updating the list.

For example...

Your `Activity`:

```
public void onEventMainThread(ListUpdateEvent event) {
    mList.add(event.getValue());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Your `Service`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ListUpdateEvent("Value to add"));
```

`ListUpdateEvent` is a simple [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that lets you share data. Using `onEventMainThread` allows you to automatically protect the list from being updated on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186995/4762282) is info about how to send messages from services to activity components. So you just need to send data about new list item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `adapter.notifiDateSetChanged();` to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

And by the way, the best way to update your activity via service is to register a broadcast receiver in your activity's `onResume()` and send a broadcast from your service when you want to update the activity and put your data as an extra. Don't forget to `unregister()` your receiver in `onPause()` and to declare your service in the Manifest.

You can read more about data flow from service via broadcast to activity here http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is not possible to update UI components in an Activity from a Service. Or, if you'd find a way to do that, I would say it is a bad idea*.

I think the EventBus implementation of Knosses is a good idea. I would like to suggest an implementation using a database, Loaders and Broadcasts.

The Activity with the ListView would use a CursorLoader to get the list content from the data source. The Service would add the items to the database each `NOTIFY_INTERVAL` and send out a Broadcast. The Activity would register a BroadcastReceiver that listens to the Broadcasts send by the Service, on receiving a Broadcast in the Activity, call `getLoaderManager().restartLoader()`, so the content in the ListView will refresh.

Edit:
* Let me elaborate a bit on that; as you can also bind a Service to your Activity. In that case, it is perfectly valid to update a UI component through the binding.